# Erro no adaptador Curl utiliznado Solarium - Solr com php 7

Tags: php-7, apache-solr

Utilizo Sorl na versão 5.4, funcionando perfeitamente a interface do próprio Solr.

Instalei o [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/) para facilitar o desenvolvimento da aplicação. Porém, ao testar os exemplos seguindo as orientações iniciais recebo o seguinte erro:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught Solarium\Exception\HttpException: Solr HTTP 
  error: HTTP request failed, Connection timed out after 5001 milliseconds in solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php:195 Stack trace: #0
  solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(92): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->check('', Array, Resource id #37) #1 
  solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(213): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->getResponse(Resource id #37, false) #2 
  solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php(68): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->getData(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Endpoint)) #3 
  solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Client.php(804): Solarium\Core\Client\Adapter\Curl->execute(Object(Solarium\Core\Client\Request), Object(Solariu in solarium/library/Solarium/Core/Client/Adapter/Curl.php on line 195
```

Tenho instalado o php7, libcurl, php-curl (php70w-common) conforme instruções encontradas no [Webtatic](https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/).

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

Obrigado!

Comment: Versão 5.4 do que? Do php? Sorl é o que, é o proprio Solarium? Se der alguns detalhes facilita a te ajudar. Muitas respostas veem de pessoas que nunca desenvolveram nos ambientes de quem pergunta, mas se der um norte facilita a ajudar. A principio o erro parece de conexão.

Comment: Olá @GuilhermeNascimento Solr 5.4 (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), Solarium é uma opção de front end para o Sorl... porém creio que já descobri o que é... o Solarium utiliza PECL Solr, que é uma biblioteca do próprio PHP para conexões, contudo, a PECL Sorl ainda não trabalha com php 7. Devem lançar agora essa semana conforme resposta do desenvolvedor. Obrigado de qualquer forma.